# Long to hexString , wrong size

Tags: android, type-conversion

I work with my custom USB Device. I get from it bytes array. I want to display this array as hex string so I convert it firstly into Long like this :

```
byte[] receivedTag = connector.receive(512);
                        String tag = null;
                        if (receivedTag != null) {
                            long tagValue = ByteBuffer.wrap(receivedTag).getLong();
```

Next I want to convert it into hex String :

```
 tag = Long.toHexString(tagValue);
```

however I've got problem here. Received Tag has something about 400 bytes (I've checked it on debug) , but when I convert it , tag is only 16 chars long(8 bytes, there are correct). Why is that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java check out this link

Comment: I found it but no solution there is correct for me

Comment: Useful Info to consider. Long has a fixed size 64bits (8bytes).

Comment: Do not convert to long first. Why would you? And it is impossible. Nothing easier then converting byte for byte to hex representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] in) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(byte b : in) {
        builder.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    } 
    return builder.toString();
}
```

// consider using this

Comment: It's better right now, but still got something about half of the bytes that should be converted - rest of them is 0 ( they shouldn't be).